# pandas.apply() returns NaN from difference between two columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to calculate the absolute differences of two pandas columns `I` and `Imean` with the following code

```
    def diff(row):
        """ calculate absolute difference of this row """
        return np.abs(row['I'] - row['Imean'])

    spectrum['diff'] = spectrum.apply(diff, axis=1)
```

Whenever `spectrum['I']` is all zeros, `spectrum['diff']` contains all `nan`. What do I miss?
(I can circumvent the error if I check `spectrum['I']` for the all-zeros case and then `spectrum['diff'] = spectrum['Imean']`. But still ...)

Info added:

Ok, I investigated further and tracked down my problem. I normalize my data by the area below the curve and try to avoid division by zero as I know that there might be all-zero data present.

```
    s = spectrum['I'].sum()
    try:
        spectrum['I'] /= s
    except ValueError:
        spectrum['I'] = 0.0
```

I get no runtime warning from my script but if I run my code in an Ipython console I get `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide` and `spectrum['I']` gets replaced by `NaN`s. The same if I use `ZeroDivisionError`.
So how do I properly avoid division by zero here?

Comment: There may be a bunch of things you missed, but the first thing I noticed that was missing was a sample data set.  Try to adhere to these standards when asking a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do it this way:

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, (10,2)), columns=['I', 'Imean'])

In [7]: df['diff'] = (df['I'] - df['Imean']).abs()

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
    I  Imean  diff
0   2      9     7
1   9      1     8
2  18     11     7
3   6     19    13
4   5     12     7
5   4      8     4
6  13      3    10
7   1     19    18
8   6      5     1
9   7      0     7
```

all zeros:

```
In [9]: df.I=0

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
   I  Imean  diff
0  0      9     7
1  0      1     8
2  0     11     7
3  0     19    13
4  0     12     7
5  0      8     4
6  0      3    10
7  0     19    18
8  0      5     1
9  0      0     7

In [11]: df['diff'] = (df['I'] - df['Imean']).abs()

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   I  Imean  diff
0  0      9     9
1  0      1     1
2  0     11    11
3  0     19    19
4  0     12    12
5  0      8     8
6  0      3     3
7  0     19    19
8  0      5     5
9  0      0     0
```

PS as [@piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38550304/pandas-apply-returns-nan-from-difference-between-two-columns#comment64491751_38550304) has already mentioned please always provide reproducible sample and desired data sets, when asking pandas questions